# Is there a way to map a raw query to a Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a complex raw SQL query that I don't want to retro-convert to query builder. Is there a way to map the result of the query to a model?

In short, I have this kind of query:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
WHERE exists (super_long_raw_query)
AND many_more_raw_where_clauses
ORDER BY something_complex
etc;
```

It only returns columns from one Model (from a table corresponding to a model).

It would be terrible and *not readable* to convert it to a "Laravel Query Builder" query:

```
User::where(/* ... */)
    ->whereExists(function() { /* super complex callback */ } )
    ->etc(/* ... */)
```

The raw query is easier (in this specific case) to read.

**Is there a way to map a raw query to a model?** (assuming it only returns the columns of a specific model)

*Side note: It's a raw query that uses query parameters (`?`, `:something`) because I don't want injections.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `fromQuery()`

```
$query = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('select * from users');
$users = \App\User::fromQuery($query, []);
```

Comment: Thank you! +1. I did not know about the `fromQuery` which is a shortcut for my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647751/978690

Answer (score 4):

You could use `hydrate` method:

```
$users = User::hydrate(
    DB::select('super_complex_query_with_params', [$params])
);
```

See: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_hydrate

Answer (score 1):

Use PDO

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM user");
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");
```

Comment: Thank you! +1. Still I found this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647751/978690 which seems more Laravel-esque (or Laravel-ish)

Comment: That is indeed more Laravel-ish! I use doctrine-dbal, but I tend to use PDO when a framework overcomplicates things. It should always be readable :-)

Answer (score -2):

You can use any of the following methods

```
DB::select('your raw query here');
```

and you can use raw expressions like

```
DB::raw('your raw query here');
```

and methods like

```
->selectRaw(''),
->whereRaw(''),
->havingRaw('')
```

Check out documentation for details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you should be extremely careful to not create SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm aware of these methods. My question is can I map a raw query to model.

Comment: I think if you need to map query to a model you need to use eloquent

Comment: may use the raw query methods with eloquent like, Model::select(DB::raw('query'))->get();

Comment: This does not answer OP's question.