# How can I write Laravel eloquent query (inner query) for this plain SQL query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM appointments
        WHERE `date` <= Curdate()
) `t`
WHERE `t`.`end_time` <= current_time
```

How can I write a Laravel [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) equivalent query for this SQL query?

Comment: Why the subselect? Couldn't you write `SELECT * FROM appointments AS \`a\` WHERE \`a\`.\`date\` <= CURDATE() AND \`a\`.\`end_time\` <= CURRENT_TIME`? So it's just `.where().where()` if I'm not missing something.

Comment: In your query, If there is a record from yesterday where end_time > current_time won't get selected

Comment: Your statement after the subselect is `WHERE \`t\`.\`end_time\` <= CURRENT_TIME`. Isn't this filtering yesterday's rows as well?

Comment: I want to select all past records. `t`.`end_time` <= CURRENT_TIME won't work if yesterdays end_time is > CURRENT_TIME

Comment: Oh okay it's a side-effect or date and time in different columns... I haven't seen this in a long time, sorry. I would write the select to compare to a [unix timestamp](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php), then one `.where()` or `.whereRaw()` call can do it.

Comment: @Joyal try this Appointment::whereExists(function ($query){
            $query->selectRaw(1)
                ->from((new Appointment())->getTable())
                ->whereDate("date",'<=',now()->format('Y-m-d'));
        })->whereDate("end_time",'<=',now()->format('H:i:s'))->get()

Comment: above query change a bit @Joyal try this Appointment::whereExists(function ($query){ $query->selectRaw(1) ->from((new Appointment())->getTable()) ->whereDate("date",'<=',now()->format('Y-m-d')); })->whereTime("end_time",'<=',now()->format('H:i:s'))->get()

Comment: Can you explain in English what this query should do?

Comment: Personally, I would go with the answer given by @Mtxz ; if, for some reason, your query is more complex and you want/need to write it raw, you could call it with the `DB:raw` method and then map the results on models with the `fromQuery` Builder method (explained better here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647365/is-there-a-way-to-map-a-raw-query-to-a-model ); just be careful with eager/lazy loading to get what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to query:

- all past appointments (from start to yesterday, based on `date` field) +
- all today appointments that have `end_time` not past (or exactly now) for today

And assuming you have a proper Model for the `appointment` table you could try something like :

```php
Appointments::where('appointments.date', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('appointments.date', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
              ->where('appointments.end_time', '<=', Carbon::now()->toTimeString());
    });
```

You may need to test the Carbon format used in `where` clauses to be sure it matches your database storage format, and the query return expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this suit you, you can try it:

```php
Appointment::whereIn('id', function($query) {
    $query->select('id')
        ->from('appointment')
        ->where('date', '<=', DB::raw('CURDATE()'));
})
->where('end_time', '<=', DB::raw('CURRENT_TIME()'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this i hope you got your solution .

```
Appointment::whereExists(function ($query){ $query->selectRaw(1) ->from((new 
Appointment())->getTable()) ->whereDate("date",'<=',now()->format('Y-m-d')); })- 
>whereDate("end_time",'<=',now()->format('H:i:s'))->get()
```